# What is meant by a "sweep" in Reinfocement Leraning?

Tags: terminology, reinforcement-learning, definition

what is meant by a sweep in value iteration or policy iteration in RL.

please try to give a nice explanation because I am new to RL.

Answer (score 1):

I saw it for the first time in Sutton's book. In the context they mentioned it is, as you said, when computing value or policy iteration, but the *inplace* variant of the algorithms.

Sometimes, the value iteration, for example, is computed using *two* value tables. The one where you are computing the state values at time step *k* and the previous one, at time step $k - 1$.
In contrast, the *inplace* algorithm does not use this auxiliary table; it updates the state values in the same table for both $k$ and $k - 1$ time steps.

The *sweeping* comes from removing of the previous state value and writing in the same place the new one.

Comment: --The sweeping comes from removing of the previous state value and writing in the same place the new one.-- Do you mean that we use new state values in iteration as early they become available for us? I mean "Do we use the updated state values in a iteration from the instant they become available for use without waiting for the next iteration??"

Comment: We can do it both ways. 1. Use state values as long as they are available to compute the new ones, and 2. Compute all the state values in iteration k using table "k-1" and then move to the next iteration